# Why does replacing $\cosh$ by $\cos$ in this biquadratic integral not change anything?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

TLDR; can I do the second integral with the method I used for the first integral?

I was reading about some integrals when I saw the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^4+2x^2\cosh(2t)+1} = \frac{\pi}{4\cosh(t)}$$

The way to do this is to write the denominator as $(x^2+e^{2t})(x^2+e^{-2t})$ and then this is simple $\arctan$ integral after partial fraction decomposition.

Then I saw another integral where cosh is replaced by cos, ie.
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^4+2x^2\cos(2t)+1}= \frac{\pi}{4\cos(t)}$$
but the way to do this integral is quite different, and in fact quite difficult (you need to do a $1/x$ sub, then add the two resulting things, then write it as half of $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ integral, then add $2x\sin(t)$ to numerator, and then you get arctan). Basically there is no way I could have thought of this...

However, even before seeing the solution to the second problem, I guessed the correct answer, and basically my reasoning was that $\cosh(2it)=\cos(2t)$ or basically in cos we just have an $i$ in the exponent and the rest of the 'form' is basically the same, so the answer should not make a difference... (so basically I thought I could do this the same way as I did the cosh integral, factorise denominator as $(x^2+e^{2it})(x^2+e^{-2it})$ and then do partial fraction stuff, but the thing is I am not familiar with using complex numbers in integrals yet, like I don't know if this type of thinking is valid or if this is mathematically possible to do integration with complex numbers...
So that is my question essentially; I want to see if it is possible to do the second integral in the way we did the first integral, and if so how? Also I would really appreciate any books/handouts/resources for learning how to do this if possible...

Comment: It is valid. if you turn into Complex definition and evaluate, finally answer when evaluatef would always be real

Comment: Do you really have two different variables, $x$ and $t$? What's your variable of integration?

Comment: @DavidK t is a fixed number, x is the variable of integration...

Comment: So that's part of the problem description, which should be in the question. (You can "edit" to fix this.) It's also helpful to the reader if you write $dx$ in the integral to signify that $x$ is the variable of integration (which also saves you the trouble of writing it in words).

Comment: @DavidK wow i somehow forgot to add that, thanks, ill keep that in mind next time (though it looks like someone already edited that in)

Answer (score 4):

Both integrals are examples of this integral,
which (as you observed) you can solve by partial fractions and arctan:

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1} \,\mathrm dx. \tag1
$$

We write
\begin{align}
\frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1}
&= \frac1{\left(x^2 + k^2\right) \left(x^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right)} \\
&= \frac1{k^2 - \frac1{k^2}} 
   \left(\frac1{x^2 + \frac1{k^2}} - \frac1{x^2 + k^2}\right).
\end{align}

We find that
\begin{align}
\int \frac1{x^2 + k^2} \,\mathrm dx
 &= \frac1k \arctan\left(\frac xk\right) + C_1, \\
\int \frac1{x^2 + \frac1{k^2}} \,\mathrm dx &= k \arctan(kx) + C_2,
\end{align}
and putting this all together, the indefinite integral is
$$
\int \frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1} \,\mathrm dx
= \frac{k \arctan(kx) - \frac1k \arctan\left(\frac xk\right)}
       {k^2 - \frac1{k^2}} + C_3.
$$

This is the point at which things get a little tricky, depending on what $k$ is. If $k$ is a positive real number then it is easy to say that in the limit as $x \to \infty$, both $\arctan(kx)$ and $\arctan\left(\frac xk\right)$
go to $\frac\pi2,$ and at $x=0$ both arc tangents are zero.
In this case the definite integral comes out to
$$
\left(\frac{k - \frac1k}{k^2 - \frac1{k^2}}\right)\frac\pi2 - 0
 = \dfrac\pi{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)}. \tag2
$$

But this doesn't generalize to all non-zero $k$.
Notice that if you replace $k$ with $(-k)$ in the integral $(1)$,
the value of the integrand does not change at all, and neither does the value of the integral (if it converges), but the supposed solution $(2)$ changes sign. So this solution cannot possibly be correct for all $k$.

---

So let's start over. I would rather deal with the complex logarithm than the complex arc tangent, so let's factor the denominator all the way to first-degree terms in $x$ when we do the partial fractions. We have

\begin{align}
&\frac1{\left(x^2 + k^2\right) \left(x^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right)}\\
&\qquad=
\frac1{(x + ik)(x - ik)\left(x + \frac ik\right)\left(x - \frac ik\right)}\\
&\qquad= \frac{i}{2\left(k^2-\frac1{k^2}\right)}
\left(\frac{k}{x+\frac ik} - \frac{k}{x-\frac ik}
 - \frac{\frac1k}{x + ik} + \frac{\frac1k}{x - ik}\right).
\end{align}

In general, we still have
$$ \int \frac1{x + a} \,\mathrm dx = \ln(x + a) + C_4 $$
even when the constant $a$ is complex, although we have to choose a branch of the $\ln$ function in order to make it single-valued. Then
\begin{align}
\int \left(\frac1{x + a} - \frac1{x - a}\right) \mathrm dx
&= \ln(x + a) - \ln(x - a) + C_5 \\
&= \ln\left(\frac{x + a}{x - a}\right) + C_6,
\end{align}
where we may choose constants $C_5$ and $C_6$ in such a way as to stay on the same branch. So

\begin{align}
&\int \frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1} \,\mathrm dx \\
&\qquad= \int \frac{i}{2\left(k^2-\frac1{k^2}\right)}
\left(\frac{k}{x+\frac ik} - \frac{k}{x-\frac ik}
 - \frac{\frac1k}{x + ik} + \frac{\frac1k}{x - ik}\right) \mathrm dx \\
&\qquad=
\frac{i}{2\left(k^2 - \frac1{k^2}\right)}  
   \left(k\ln\left(\frac{x + \frac ik}{x - \frac ik}\right)
     - \frac1k \ln\left(\frac{x + ik}{x - ik}\right)\right) + C_7 \\
&\qquad= F(x) + C_7,
\end{align}

where the function $F(x)$ is defined by the much less concise expression on the previous line.

To evaluate the definite integral, we want the antiderivative $F(x)$ to be continuous at all positive real $x$.
A way to do this is to ensure that the logarithms in the formula above stay on the same sheet as $x$ increases from $0$ to $\infty.$
We can do that by choosing a branch cut to make the logarithm single-valued, but doing so in a way that prevents either
$\dfrac{x + ik}{x - ik}$ or $\dfrac{x + i/k}{x - i/k}$
from crossing the branch cut.

To make a long story short -- meaning I am skipping a lot of steps here --
for $k$ not a pure imaginary number,
as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$ the complex numbers
$\dfrac{x + ik}{x - ik}$ and $\dfrac{x + i/k}{x - i/k}$
travel along circular arcs in the complex plane starting at $0$ (when $x=0$)
and approaching $1$ in the limit as $x$ goes to $\infty.$
If $\Re(k)$ (the real part of $k$) is positive, the arcs are in the upper half plane (positive imaginary part), but if $\Re(k)$ is negative, the arcs are in the lower half plane. To avoid having one of these arcs cross the branch cut, we could choose the branch cut depending on the real part of $k$, or we can take a branch cut along the positive $x$ axis, which is what we will do here. We will also use the sheet of the logarithm for which $\ln(-1) = i\pi.$ Then

$$
\int_0^\infty \frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2+\frac1{k^2}\right) + 1} \,\mathrm dx
= \left(\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)\right) - F(0).
$$

On our chosen sheet of the logarithm, as $z$ approaches $1$ from above, $F(x)$ goes to $0$, and as as $z$ approaches $1$ from above, $F(x)$ goes to $2\pi.$
That is, if $\Re(k) > 0$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{x + \frac ik}{x - \frac ik}\right)
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{x + ik}{x - ik}\right) = 0
$$
and therefore $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = 0$,
whereas if $\Re(k) < 0$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{x + \frac ik}{x - \frac ik}\right)
= \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln\left(\frac{x + ik}{x - ik}\right) = 2\pi
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) =
\frac{i}{2\left(k^2-\frac1{k^2}\right)} \left(i2\pi k - \frac{i2\pi}k\right)
= - \frac{\pi}{k + \frac1k}.
$$

Meanwhile, in either case,
$$
F(0) = \frac{i}{2\left(k^2-\frac1{k^2}\right)}
          \left(k\ln(-1) - \frac1k\ln(-1)\right)
= - \frac{\pi}{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)}.
$$

In conclusion, for $k$ with a positive real part we have
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1}\,\mathrm dx
= 0 - \left(- \frac{\pi}{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)}\right)
= \frac{\pi}{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)}
$$
while for $k$ with a negative real part we have
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4 + x^2 \left(k^2 + \frac1{k^2}\right) + 1}\,\mathrm dx
= - \frac{\pi}{k + \frac1k}
 - \left(- \frac{\pi}{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)}\right)
= - \frac{\pi}{2\left(k + \frac1k\right)},
$$
consistent with the observation of what ought to happen when we replace $k$ by $-k$ in these equations.

If $k$ is pure imaginary then neither of these approaches works.
In that case I'm reasonably sure the integral does not converge.

---

Now let $k = e^t,$ and then $k^2 + \frac1{k^2} = 2\cosh(2t)$
and $k + \frac1k = 2\cosh(t).$ Since the real part of $k$ is positive for every real constant $t,$
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4 + 2x^2 \cosh(2t) + 1}\,\mathrm dx
= \frac{\pi}{2\cosh(t)}.
$$
Alternatively, let $k = e^{it},$ and then $k^2 + \frac1{k^2} = 2\cos(2t)$
and $k + \frac1k = 2\cos(t)$. Then $\Re(k) > 0$ if and only if $\cos(t) > 0,$ in which case
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^4 + 2x^2 \cos(2t) + 1}\,\mathrm dx
= \frac{\pi}{2\cos(t)}.
$$
But if $\cos(t) < 0$ then we have to change the sign of the result.
This makes me wonder about the proof you found that supposedly
solved this integral; did it explicitly assume $\cos(t) > 0$
or did it subtly ignore a possible sign error in one of the steps?

Comment: Thanks, but this is kind of precisely my doubt, is it mathematically valid/ always possible to do integrals this way, by this way i mean in the cos integral, k is an imaginary number, so is it ok to do integrals but have complex numbers as constants lying there? also, could you please tell me where it is possible to learn this technique of using complex numbers in real integrals? This is not a contour integral which is why i was kinda confused if i could do that...

Comment: There are complications of the arctan substitution that require some care, and I see I have not taken care enough. There needs to be a restriction on $k$ or a way of reversing the sign of the answer depending on $k$. In particular, notice that if we simply replace a given value of $k$ by $-k$, the integral on the left doesn't change but the solution on the right changes sign, so this solution works for $k$ on at most half of the complex plane. Let me spend some time on that.

Comment: Note that this is going to be a problem with the cosine version of the integral no matter how we solve it. If we consider only real values of $t$, the integral is always positive, but $\cos(t)$ can be negative, implying that $\pi/(4\cos(t))$ is negative. So the solution that you found is incorrect when $\cos(t)<0.$